# MongoDB Atlas Using Parse Server On AWS :: MongoError: no valid replicaset members found

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, parse-platform, mongodb-atlas

I have configured MongoDB Atlas using parse.com on Aws, Configuration done for MongoDB Atlas Cluster. I am able to connect to Mongo Atlas cluster using SSH, And I am also able to connect to Mongo Atlas Cluster using my localhost parse.com library. But when I try to connect to Mongo Atlas using parse server on AWS getting below error

```
Uncaught internal server error. { MongoError: no valid replicaset members found
at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/application/juicebarParse/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:660:33)
at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5) name: 'MongoError' 
message: 'no valid replicaset members found' } MongoError: no valid 
replicaset members found
at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/application/juicebarParse/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:660:33)
at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

Below is my **connection string**

```
mongodb://crajput:PASSWORD@cluster0-shard-00-00-qhwh9.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-qhwh9.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-qhwh9.mongodb.net:27017/DB_NAME?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&ssl=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating parse server to a latest version solved this problem.